# Adjust formatRound of my output$table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like some help regarding the `formatRound` of my `output$table` in my code. The code works fine, but I'd like to make an adjustment that goes like this: as you can see I specify `formatRound`, as being `formatRound(c(3:4))`, but instead of inserting `4`, I'd like to do something like this: `c(3:ncol(All))`, however when I do it appears object `All` not found and it also doesn't work if I insert `c(3:last_col())`, do you know how I can adjust this, that is, I wouldn't like to specify the last column in `formatRound`?

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)

    data_subset <- reactive({
      req(input$daterange1)
      req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
      days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
     All<- subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
     All<-All%>% mutate(date2 = format(ymd(date2), "%d/%m/%Y"))%>%
        mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
        mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-')))
  })
    
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
     datatable(data_subset(),options = list( columnDefs = list(
          list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
        paging = TRUE,  searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,dom = 'tip',  scrollx=TRUE),    rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(c(3:4), digits=0)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reactive object.  `All` is an object created within the `reactive` element and it is not acessible.  Instead, get the output with `data_subset()` and wrap with `ncol`

```
      formatRound(3:ncol(data_subset()), digits=0)
```

-server code

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    All<- subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    All<-All%>% mutate(date2 = format(ymd(date2), "%d/%m/%Y"))%>%
      mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-')))
  })
  
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
    datatable(data_subset(),options = list( columnDefs = list(
      list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
      paging = TRUE,  searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,dom = 'tip',  scrollx=TRUE),    rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(3:ncol(data_subset()), digits=0)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Or instead of doing `data_subset()` multiple times, assign it to an object and use that object

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    All<- subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    All<-All%>% mutate(date2 = format(ymd(date2), "%d/%m/%Y"))%>%
      mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-')))
  })
  
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    All <- data_subset()
    datatable(All,options = list( columnDefs = list(
      list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
      paging = TRUE,  searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,dom = 'tip',  scrollx=TRUE),    rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(3:ncol(All), digits=0)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun, it works! =)